# Spring 4 WebSockets subscribe to a topic

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Is it possible to map a method in a spring managed bean to a topic subscription using spring messaging?

I've looked at the examples here: http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html
including the example stock application but it looks like all topic subscription is on the client side. Is it possible to also subscribe to topics on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMS to subscribe to the topic.

```
public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            }
            catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }
}





   <!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
    <bean id="messageListener" class="jmsexample.ExampleListener" />

    <!-- and this is the message listener container -->
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>
```

More here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html